# Google Sign-in in vuejs spa and laravel api

Tags: laravel, vue.js, vuejs2, google-signin, laravel-5.5

I have a single page application with `vue.js` that uses `Laravel 5.5` as its api. I want to add google sign-in to it but I am confused as where to start. I have  used `laravel socialite` before to add google sign-in but that was for pure laravel application and not a laravel api.

Can anyone point to  to some resources I can read. Is there a package like socialite for this, Is there a way to use socialite to use in this case as well.

Comment: There is a vuejs component for this now. https://github.com/phanan/vue-google-signin-button

Answer (score 4):

Take a look at [hellojs](https://adodson.com/hello.js/)

Hellojs makes it easy. Allows you to open a popup for login with the social provider and returns an access token. then you use the access token in your backend to get the user.

so your js would look something like this

```
 hello
  .login(network)
  .then(
    () => {
      const authRes = hello(network).getAuthResponse();
      axios
        .get('api/link/to/sociak/callback',{
            params:{
              access_token : authRes.access_token, 
              provider: network
            }
         })
        .then((response) => {console.log(response.data.token)})})
        .catch((error) => {console.log(error.response.data)})
    },
    (e) => {
      console.log(e)
    }
  )
```

and in your controller you handle it like ..

```
public function handleProviderCallback(Request $request)
{
    $s_user = Socialite::with($request->provider)->stateless()->userFromToken($request->access_token);
    //your logic here...
}
```

Hope it makes it clearer for you. I was just struggling with this and hello js made my life simple

Answer (score 1):

In adition to the previous answer, i used [vue-hellojs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/vue-hellojs) to add the goolgle's authentication window and get a token (**with 'email, profile' scope**).

Then send it to the laravel backend (with [google socialite provider](https://socialiteproviders.netlify.com/providers/google.html) and CORS installed) who check if there is a user with that email and respond with a laravel [jwt-token](http://jwt-auth.com/) to the vue SPA as login do.